# How to execute the multiple http request methods in a loop(map or _.each) in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am facing a problem in executing the chain based http request methods in a map(loop).But it executing in the form of asynchronous (means it executes the **firstFun** and then **secondFun**), but i want it in synchronous way to execute. when the first fun is calling then in that the request method is called and use the request response to second fun request and call that method.

**This is the code:**

```
var pipelines = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var auth_token = "xxxxxxxx"

getPipelinesTOTrigger(pipelines , auth_token) 
function getPipelinesTOTrigger(pipelines , auth_token, cb) {

    pipelines.map(function (pipe) {
        firstFun(pipe,function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err:" + JSON.stringify(err))
            } else {daya
                console.log("first fun return :" + JSON.stringify(data.status))
                secondFun(data, function (err, data1) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("err:" + err)
                    } else {
                        console.log("second fun return "+JSON.stringify(data1.status))

                    }
                })
            }
        })

     })
}

function firstFun(pipe, cb) {
    var pipe = { pipe: pipe }
     var options = {
        method: "GET",
        url:"https://abc.myappdemo.us/api/singlePublish/597ebfcfa5a4ea23a233ce93",

       headers: {

             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
        },


          };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {

            if(error){
                console.log(error)
            }

var jsondata=JSON.parse(body)
    return cb(null, jsondata)

})
}

function secondFun(pipe, cb) {
    var pipe = { data: pipe.pipe * 2 }
         var options = {
        method: "GET",
        url:"https://abc.myappdemo.us/api/singlePublish/597ebfcfa5a4ea23a233ce93",

       headers: {

             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
        },

          };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {

            if(error){
                console.log(error)
            }

var jsondata1=JSON.parse(body)
    return cb(null, jsondata1)

})

}
```

**I am getting the output like this:**

```
first fun return :"Success"
first fun return :"Success"
first fun return :"Success"
first fun return :"Success"
second fun return "Success"
second fun return "Success"
second fun return "Success"
second fun return "Success"
```

**but i want like this:**

```
first fun return :"Success"
second fun return "Success"
first fun return :"Success"
second fun return "Success"
first fun return :"Success"
second fun return "Success"
first fun return :"Success"
second fun return "Success"
```

Please help me to solve this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reduce() and Promises to Execute Multiple Async Calls Sequentially.

For more details please check the article to [here](https://blog.hellojs.org/use-reduce-and-promises-to-execute-multiple-async-calls-sequentially-4caf03a34b9a) and [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

And try to use following code it will help you for your result.

```
        // include bluebird in your file
        var Promise = require("bluebird");

        var pipelines = [1, 2, 3, 4];

        function getPipelinesTOTrigger(pipelines , auth_token) {
          return pipelines.reduce((promise, item) => {
            return promise
              .then((result) => {
                return firstFun(item);
              })
              .then((result) => {
                return secondFun(item);
              })
              .catch(console.error);
          }, Promise.resolve());
        }

        function firstFun(pipe){
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              console.log('first', pipe);
              resolve({'first': 'Success', 'pipe': pipe});
          });
        }

        function secondFun(pipe){
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              console.log('second', pipe);
              resolve({'second': 'Success', 'pipe': pipe})
          });
        }
```

If you need first fun result in second and then collect the total result , use following method.

```
    return Promise.map(pipelines, function(pipe) {
      return firstFun(pipe)
      .then(function(firstFunResult) {
          //get result from first fun
          return secondFun(pipe, firstFunResult);
      })
      .then(function(finalResult) {
        //get Final result from second fun
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
          //("Error occurred ", err.message, err.stack);
      });
    })
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please check same code from https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84

Comment: yes it executes fine but when I using the http request methods then it is not executes synchronous and i want to use the first function response in second function.please look at my code at above.

Comment: Okay then use Promise.map method of bluebird and call your promises in that it will return first output to second as input sequentially

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach using [async waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall). I have replaced the network call with `setTimeout()` and mock data.

```
'use strict';

var pipelines = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var auth_token = "xxxxxxxx";
let async = require('async');

getPipelinesTOTrigger(pipelines, auth_token);

function getPipelinesTOTrigger(pipelines, auth_token) {
  for (let i = 0; i < pipelines.length; i++) {
    let pipe = pipelines[i];
    async.waterfall([
      function (callback) {
        firstFun(pipe, callback);
      }, function (data, callback) {
        secondFun(pipe, data, callback);
      }], function (err, json) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(`err while processing ${i}, pipe = ${pipe}`, err);
      }
      console.log(json);
    });
  }
}

function firstFun(pipe, cb) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    cb(null, `success - ${pipe}`);
  }, 2000);
}

function secondFun(pipe, data, cb) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    cb(null, `firstFun return ${data} secondFun return Success - ${data}`);
  }, 2000);
}
```

This produces

```
firstFun return success - 1 secondFun return Success - success - 1
firstFun return success - 2 secondFun return Success - success - 2
firstFun return success - 3 secondFun return Success - success - 3
firstFun return success - 4 secondFun return Success - success - 4
```